# Can the interaction history of objects be tracked (for debugging purposes)?

Tags: debugging, metaprogramming

I'm working on a Java project where I create a lot of objects in one module, then send them all over to a second module to handle them there.

Now, if an object is found to contain invalid stuff I will need to do detective work to figure out what part of the first module caused the error. It's not overwhelming but it  seems it would be a lot easier if there were some way to simply track the interactions of an object and what methods have used it/called its mutators/constructors.

Comment: Seems to me that this is not available today but being researched:
http://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/handle/10012/5144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're discussing is one of the main goodies offered by historical/reversible debuggers. In the Java space there is the [Chronon debugger](http://www.chrononsystems.com/) that just came out of beta, that should allow you to track an object instnace over the run of an application.

Also, some IDEs have Data Flow Analysis tools, that allow you to track exactly where a certain property of the object is changed, and where the value comes from. In the .NET space there is [Resharper Value Tracking](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/03/resharper-50-preview-value-tracking/), but I'm not sure if there's an equivalent to that in the Java world.